# How much percent of one's income should be given to charity?

Tags: upanishads, rig-veda, brihadaranyaka-upanishad, daana

Daana has been [praised in the Rig Veda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%81na#D.C4.81na_in_Hindu_scriptures) and the Upanishads.

---

The Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 5.2.3. says

> तदेतत्त्रयँ शिक्षेद् दमं दानं दयामिति

essentially glorifying generosity, compassion and mental restraint.

---

According to Hinduism, what percentage of one's income should be donated?

Comment: I think it says in the Manu Smriti.

Answer (score 5):

Meaning of **daan (दान)** - to bestow ,to dispose ,to donate ,to endow.[See here](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/hindi-english/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8)

The Daan(दान) should only be made with the money leftover after fullfilling the requirements of family. Daan should not result hardship to donars family or loss of livelyhood.In general only those who have surplus wealth are required to give.

Scriptures lay down varying proportion of one's income (ranging from 10% to 40%) to give away in daan.

**Skanda Puran(स्कंद पुराण) -** According to Skanda puran one should 10% of one's justly earned income on good deeds or works of pubilc benifit.

**Bhagwat puran(भागवत पुराण)** - At one stage, when **"Sukhracharya"** advices king **"Bali"** against giving all his wealth away. He quotes learned people to recommend dividing one's fund into five equal parts.

1) One part should be used for Dharma (daan).

2) Second for Yash (public works ,which brings fame to oneself).

3) Third should be re-invested for generating more wealth.

4) Forth for "Kaam"(काम) or material enjoyment.

5) Fifth for one's family and friends.[See Here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=tazZHHgu4DAC&pg=PT46&lpg=PT46&dq=how%20much%20daan%20one%20should%20give&source=bl&ots=EIIgUCngaO&sig=4UKIGOqwLXY2iX75mSE6tiQ5Z5E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip6YCtqYLPAhUMq48KHXAtDqEQ6AEIMjAJ#v=onepage&q=how%20much%20daan%20one%20should%20give&f=false)

**Importance of Charity (Danam)**

> **आदानां दोषेण भवेद्दारिद्रम। दारिद्र्य दोषेण करोति पापं ।।**
>
> **पापदावस्यां नरकं प्रयान्ति। पुनर दरिद्रो पुनरेव: पापी ।।**
>
> “Adana Doshena Bhaveddaridram Daridraya Doshena Karothi papam
>   Papadavasyam Narakam Prayathi Punar Dadidro Punareva Papi.”
>
> **Meaning** - Great men think that poverty comes to man as a result of his
>   miserly deeds of his past birth. A man should,as sastras say, donate
>   some of his earning to the poor. He should cultivate the habit of
>   doing charitable deeds. Otherwise in his next birth he will again be
>   born as a poor man who will be forced to do sinful deeds and as a
>   result of which he will be placed Narakam [Hell] and after receiving
>   punishment in Hell, he will be born again as a poor man:
>
> **दारिद्रय:कुतं दानं। शून्य: लिंगस्च पूजनं।। अन्धा प्रेत: संस्कारं।
>   अश्वमेध: समं विदुहु।।**
>
> “Daridraya Krutam Danam Soonya Limgascha poojanam Anadha Pretha
>   Samskaram Aswamedha samam viduhu.’’
>
> **Meaning** - Helping the poor with money, doing ‘Archana’/’pooja’
>   [worship] to the Shiva Lingam of a dilapidated temple, doing funeral
>   rites to the corpse of an orphan are equal to doing **Aswamedha Yagam**.

[Shloka source](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.anantaajournal.com/archives/2015/vol1issue4/PartA/Sanskrit-1-3-41.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjY-sm9yILPAhVBpo8KHYLRDdsQFggnMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHqtFcPXl4VA4K3wVx3Ywd-pV1GXw&sig2=5lEdGCqxhI65c6D0KGTjWg)

Comment: Can you tell the exact shloka number or shloka "of skanda purana", where 10% has been mentioned?