# Which shastra says about giving 10% of the income in charity?

Tags: dharma, daana

Actually, i saw this in a tv serial, and heard it also many times. Which scripture says it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much percent of one's income should be given to charity?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/how-much-percent-of-ones-income-should-be-given-to-charity)

Comment: You can give more too

Comment: I think I have read about this in Mahabharat as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to **Skanda Purana**, one should use 10% of one's justly earned income on good deeds or works of public benefit. (Mahe. Kand. 12.32)

Comment: https://dharmawiki.org/index.php/Dana_(%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D)

Answer (score -2):

in bhagwat puran when you read the story of bali raja and baman avtar you will find this explanation that a person should use that much amounts of charity so that it doesn't effect his yash arth kama and moksha or 10% of his earning